# How to list current package versions in OPAM?

Tags: ocaml, opam

`opam list -a` lists all packages currently available at OPAM, but does not display the version number for packages which are not currently installed, as per the `opam list --help` output:

> (...) the output format displays one package per line, and each line contains the name of the package, the installed version or -- if the package is not installed, (...)

How can I list all packages including their version numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A refined (and quicker) version of anol's answer is to give the whole list of packages to `opam show` in one pass (asking `opam` to output both `package` and `version` field), and to process the result with `sed`, as apparently `show` outputs each field on its own line:

```
opam show -f package,version $(opam list -a -s) \
 | sed -e '/ *package:/N; s/ *package: \([^\n]*\)\n *version: \([^\n]*\)/\1: \2/'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `opam info <packagename>`.

I guess `opam list` does only prints the versions of already installed packages because of the package dependencies. Listing the latest versions of packages, for example, of not-yet-installed packages is not quite useful.

Comment: The issue with `opam info` is that it only accepts one package at a time, for instance if I want to quickly see the latest versions of every `mirage*` package, I have to list all of them and then individually query for each version.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal solution, but using camlspotter's recommandation, I manually queried each package for its `version` field, using the following shell loop:

```
for p in $(opam list -a -s); do echo "$p $(opam show -f version $p)"; done
```

It works, but it takes ~85 seconds to complete on my machine (querying over 1000 packages currently available).